# Encoding HTML character in Yii

Tags: yii

I have the following code
CHtml::encode($model->item);

In controller, I am manipulating $model->item adding space as `&nbsp;`
Something like this

```
foreach($many_items as $key => $value){
  $model->item .= $value;
  $model->item .= '&nbsp;';
}
```

Now, in view, I see  `&nbsp;` even though I just want to see a space.
Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the relevant view code.

Comment: Don't generate HTML in the controller. Put all `$many_items` into an array, store that somewhere in `$model`, then compose it into a string (run each `$value` through `CHtml::encode` first, instead of encoding the result string) and build any HTML you need in the view.

Answer (score 1):

If it was just label or text to show up on view, you should not encode it.
Look at the sample code to see what happened

```
$abc = "<span>1</span>&nbsp;<span>2</span>";
echo CHtml::encode($abc);
echo $abc;
```

Output

```
<span>1</span>&nbsp;<span>2</span> <!-- encoded -->
1 2 // <!--  just print out directly when you put it on the label or print out HTML code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

When you encode something into html, the special characters are turned into HTML. For example:

```
echo CHtml::encode('"'); // outputs &quot;
```

What you need is neither decoding nor encoding; just stick the &nbsp; character at the end of your strings and it should work.

As a form of best practices and code readability, however, I suggest you cut this part out of your controller and put it in a widget. This will help you:

- Separate presentation from code
- Have thinner controllers, which means your code is more testable and readable